# Can I increase difficulty and drops through a command?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2, if you wanted a higher difficulty in single player, you could type `/players 8` to make the game scale the difficulty, experience, and drops to what it'd be if there were 8 players in game.

Does Diablo 3 have an equivalent? I was not able to find anything in the D3 FAQ, so I would suspect it does not. Are there any methods for increasing the difficulty/exp/drops other than playing at a higher difficulty level?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This system is being added in [patch 1.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7528695/7528695#features) (it is referred to as Monster Power).  Details are available on the official [Diablo III blog](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7540457/) .

You first need to select "Enable Monster Power Selection" on the game play tab of Options.  You will then be able to select your desired monster power level from 0 (off) to 10 in the Quest Selection interface.
[image: Screenshot of the Quest Selection screen showing the Monster Power selection menu to the right of the regular difficulty selector]

Here is a quote from the blog regarding the "/players 8" asked above.

> Similar to the "Players X" command in Diablo II, Monster Power gives Diablo III players the option to increase the health and damage of monsters according to different "power levels" -- and in return, they'll receive scaling bonuses to their adventure stats (including experience, Magic Find, and Gold Find) as well as more drops.

Here are some of the charts as of 1.0.5:
[image: Normal, Nightmare, and Hell chart]

[image: Inferno chart]]

**UPDATE**:  An updated version of the Inferno chart for [1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8608455/patch-107-now-live-2-12-2013#general):  http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8920082006

Comment: that is pretty sweet...

Comment: This answer deserves a lot of upvotes, extremely cool!

Comment: And how does this interact with more players?

Answer (score 5):

**There is no single player per se in Diablo 3**. Every game is a session running on a Blizzard server and can potentially be joined by other players.

A technique like setting the number of players to increase drop quality/difficulty/experience would not have made much sense, and therefore is not available in Diablo 3.

Comment: Such a bummer. I would've liked the games I play solo to feature some way for me to get increased gold/drops and harder monsters :-/.

Comment: @ChristopherAden Should've researched the game before you bought it eh? :).

Comment: I've been a fan of the series since the first one. It's still a great game, but I suppose I'm partial to D2 :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, which is a shame. I would have liked to have seen an actual difficulty setting rather than the purely 'progression increases difficulty' approach Diablo3 uses.